# To place a logo next to navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

Consider this markup:

```
 <nav>
    <div id="logo"><img src="logo.png" height="44PX"/></div>
       <ul id="navItems">
                    <li><a href="#"">Link1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
       </ul>
 </nav>
```

I used this css code for styling:

```
#navItems
{ 
    display:flex;
    z-index:1;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    background-color:#333;
    width:92%;
    height:44px;
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

How to place the logo on the left, just next to the navbar?

Comment: You could use a table row, and have them as two separate tds.  Or you could try `float: left;` on the div.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I made you the **simplest** possible navbar

***[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Microsmsm/wk6hzpe8/1/)***

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}
ul img {
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <img src="http://doc.jsfiddle.net/_downloads/jsfiddle-logo.png" alt="">
    <li><a href="#">Link1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: but you placed the logo "inside" the bar, not next to it

Comment: one second and it will be outside :D !

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `display:flex`, can't you just use `display:inline-flex`?

```css
#logo {
  display: inline-flex;
}

#navItems
{ 
  display:inline-flex;
  z-index:1;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  background-color:#333;
  width:92%;
  height:44px;
  list-style-type:none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div id="logo"><img src="logo.png" height="44PX"/></div>
  <ul id="navItems">
    <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: hot to fix the logo?